# Using split and reading both ints and strings from one line in a file but it doesnt print anything

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

The problem is to read a string and int from a text file separated by one space. (e.g. "3.3 Jack"). I tried using the split method as well and it appears to not be printing anything. Just a beginner!

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));

        double[] grades = new double[6];
        String[] names = new String[6];
        String s = reader.nextLine();
        String[] split = s.split(" ");

        int sum= 0;
        int counter= 0;
        int avg= 0;
            while(reader.hasNext()) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= grades.length; i++) {
                    grades[i] = Double.valueOf(split[0]);
                    names[i]= split[1];
                    sum+=grades[i];
                    counter++;
                    avg= sum/counter;

                }
                System.out.println(avg);
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach is upside down ! Why do you need `reader.hasNext()` after reading the entire line? You only need to read the line -> split it -> then check for each value at each index in the array.. Also what the format of your text in the file, does each line contain numbers and strings randomly (i.e. no specific order)?

Comment: As Yahya noted, the while block is not being executed because you already read the line

Comment: @Yahya something like "4.4 bob" in one line, one whitespace

Comment: Is it always an `float` followed by a `space` followed by a `string` and that for every line in the file?

Comment: Yes, that is the order

Comment: Change your for declaration to for (int i = 0; i <= grades.length - 1; i++)

Comment: I'm so stupid guys, haha. Beginner mistakes

Comment: Insight is enlightening. But try to be more polite towards people - including yourself. ;-)

Comment: You should have mentioned that all the data are on one SINGLE line in your file!

Comment: @Yahya So, it worked for that but when I tried adding more values to my files the average doesnt change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs, because you are verifying if "i <= grades.length", change it to "i < grades.length" and remove the while, like that:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("./data.txt"));

    double[] grades = new double[6];
    String[] names = new String[6];
    String s = reader.nextLine();
    String[] split = s.split(" ");

    int sum= 0;
    int counter= 0;
    int avg= 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            grades[i] = Double.valueOf(split[0]);
            names[i]= split[1];
            sum+=grades[i];
            counter++;
            avg= sum/counter;            
            System.out.println(avg);
        }
```

If you want to read all lines you can do that:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("./data.txt"));

    double[] grades = new double[6];
    String[] names = new String[6];        
    String[] split;

    int sum= 0;
    int counter= 0;
    int avg= 0;
        do {
            split = reader.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                grades[i] = Double.valueOf(split[0]);
                names[i]= split[1];
                sum+=grades[i];
                counter++;
                avg= sum/counter;            
                System.out.println(avg);
            }               
        } while(reader.hasNext());
```

You can use do-while to first execute and after that you verify if you have more lines.

Comment: Thanks, but when I run this code it only prints one of the values and not all 6 of them from the file

Comment: Can you explain the idea of your code? So, maybe I can help you.

Comment: If I use a print statement to print a number, it only prints one of the values. I just want to be able to store both ints and strings in seperate arrays